# How to parse XML attribute (string) to (int) during the LINQ query

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I've got a class:

```
public class Layout
{
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

How do I read the XML attribute and assign it to int from the class above in the following LINQ query:

```
var layouts =
    from elem in layoutSummary.Descendants("Layout")
    select new Layout
    {
        // Width = elem.Attribute("Width").Value,  // Invalid cast string to int)
        // Int32.TryParse((string)elem.Attribute("Height").Value, Height) // Doesn't assign Height value to Layout.Height
    };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var layouts =  from elem in layoutSummary.Descendants("Layout")
               select new ComicLayout
               {
                   Width = (int) elem.Attribute("Width"),
                   Height = (int) elem.Attribute("Height")
               };
```

This uses the explicit conversion operator available from `XAttribute` to `int`, whose MSDN page you can find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358993.aspx).

Now obviously, this will throw a `FormatException` if the conversion doesn't succeed. If that's not what you want, please indicate what you would like to happen. It *is* possible (if somewhat inconvenient) to use `int.TryParse` here, but it would have to be done differently.

Comment: That's exactly what I was after. The XML files are read-only and hard-embedded in the application. I can get away without handling failed conversion. Thank you!

Comment: The MSDN page says nothing about Culture (locale).  I hope the converter uses is culture-invariant - i.e. a mate for `XmlConvert.ToString`; an ordinary `TryParse` would use the current culture unless you explicitly pass something else in.

Answer (score 3):

Try `Convert.ToInt32` method

```
 select new ComicLayout
    {
         Width = Convert.ToInt32( elem.Attribute("Width").Value),
         Height = Convert.ToInt32(elem.Attribute("Height").Value)
    };
```

Comment: Thanks. Much appreciated. Ani's solution seems simpler. Are there any benefits in using Convert.ToInt32 as opposed to plain casting?

Answer (score 2):

```
 select new ComicLayout
 {
      Width = elem.Attribute("Width") != null ?
              Convert.ToInt32(elem.Attribute("Width").Value) :
              -1,
      Height = elem.Attribute("Height")  != null ? 
               Convert.ToInt32(elem.Attribute("Height").Value) :
               -1,
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Width = int.Parse(elem.Attribute("Width").Value)
```

or

```
int w;
if (int.TryParse(elem.Attribute("Width").Value, out w)
    Width = w;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `Convert.ToInt32`

I would also recommend adding checks to make sure it is an int so that you're not trying convert "three" to an integer. But I guess it depends on how much control you have over the xml coming back.

Comment: The XML is going to be embedded into the application at build time and read-only